# Parsing Log in Java

Tags: java, logging

How can I parse the following log in Java

```
2016-08-07 11:06:14 170226 [default task-1] INFO  com.test.intl.ads.server.security.UserLoginHandler  - Session is null 
2016-08-07 11:06:14 170231 [default task-1] INFO  com.test.intl.ads.server.security.UserLoginHandler  - Need construct new Token
```

I have used

```
String logEntryPattern = "([\\w]+\\s[\\d]+\\s[\\d:]+)\\s([\\w]+)\\s([\\w]+)\\[.+\\]:\\s(.+)";
```

But this is not working.

Here is my code

```
    String logEntryLine = null;       
    String logEntryPattern = "([\\w]+\\s[\\d]+\\s[\\d:]+)\\s([\\w]+)\\s([\\w]+)\\[.+\\]:\\s(.+)";

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuffer logBuff =  new StringBuffer("");
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Arijit\\Test1.log")); 
        int  i =0;
        while ((logEntryLine = br.readLine()) != null) {                
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(logEntryPattern);
            Matcher matcher = p.matcher(logEntryLine);
            if (!matcher.matches()) {
                System.err.println("Bad log entry (or problem with RE?):");
                System.err.println(logEntryLine);
                continue;
            }
            /*System.out.println("Date&Time: " + matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("Hostname: " + matcher.group(2));
            System.out.println("Program Name: " + matcher.group(3));
            System.out.println("Log: " + matcher.group(4));*/
        } 
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
     br.close();
    }
```

Comment: You should try this directly with an online regex tool first, this would be easier to test ;)

Comment: Also, you don't seem to realize that when working with regex, there are two expensive operations: parsing the pattern, and inspecting a very long string. You'll get horrible performance when parsing large files, constructing separate pattern for each line like that.

Comment: I am not an expert in regex, far from it .. but here is a simple one that will give you 5 group (timestamp, host, programe, level, log) `([\d-]{10}\s+[\d:]+)\s+(\w+)\s+\[([\w\s-]+)\]\s+(\w+)\s+(.*)`. Tested with your first line in [regex 101] (https://regex101.com/). Now, I would be tempted to parse one of our log folder with that ... we have many Go of logs ... this would be funny to drink coffee waiting for the process to end ;) ! But for a one time, this would works.

Comment: Thanks AxelH. It helps :).

Comment: Just One thing ..  in that Log - I want to split "com.test.intl.ads.server.security.UserLoginHandler  - Session is null" into "com.test.intl.ads.server.security.UserLoginHandler" and "Session is null"

Comment: Simply update the regex to add a group. Here the separator is a `-`.

Comment: Please send me the reg exp ..

Comment: **Please try** ... if you don't try yourself, what's the point to ask... regex are complex but the basics (like here)  are simple enough to be learn in less than an hour.

Comment: Hi .. Got it .. ([\\d-]{10}\\s+[\\d:]{8}+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+\\[([\\w\\s-]+)\\]\\s+(\\w+)\\s+([\\w\\.]+)\\s+(\\-\\s+)+(.*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick regex made from the line :

```
2016-08-07 11:06:14 170226 [default task-1] INFO  com.test.intl.ads.server.security.UserLoginHandler  - Session is null
```

Regex :  `([\d-]{10}\s+[\d:]{8})\s+(\w+)\s+\[([\w\s-]+)\]\s+(\w+)\s+(.*)`

This would give you :

```
Group 1. 0-19 `2016-08-07 11:06:14` 
Group 2. 20-26 `170226` 
Group 3. 28-42 `default task-1` 
Group 4. 44-48 `INFO` 
Group 5. 50-120 `com.test.intl.ads.server.security.UserLoginHandler  - Session is null `
```

Basicly :

```
Group 1. ([\d-]{10}\s+[\d:]{8})
```

10 character `[\d-]` followed by spaces then 8 character `[\d:]`

```
Group 2. (\w+)
```

the next block (between space)

```
Group 3. \[([\w\s-]+)\]
```

the next block (between `[]`)

```
Group 4. (\w+)
```

the next block (between space)

```
Group 5. (.*)
```

the rest of the line